# Singapore Tourist Visa for Indian in USA with F1 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, singapore

I'm an Indian citizen studying in the United States on an **F1** visa. I am traveling to **Singapore** with my parents for 4 days. How do I apply for the Singapore tourist visa in the USA? Is the process for me exactly the same as any other Indian citizen?

Answer (score 2):

You are here in the US with a multi-entry **non-visitor visa**, this is generally acceptable for consulates to allow you to use their consular services (ie visa request) here in the US. You would lodge an application with the nearest diplomatic mission.

You can find a list of Singapore Missions in the USA [here](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/Overseas-Missions/Find-A-Singapore-Overseas-Mission?letter=u).

- San Francisco (consulate)
- Miami (consulate)
- New York (consulate)
- Washington DC (embassy)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have US visa, you are eligible for Visa Free Transit Facility, if you are transiting Singapore for less than 96 hours. That means, you can enter Singapore if you are visiting a third country along.

Details and eligibility: https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf

However, you can apply for Singapore Visa via travel agencies in US, as most probably they won't accept a walk in requests. Singapore usually provide 1 month and above visa for tourism and social visits. Apply for multiple entry visa even if you are not using, as it costs the same.